WPF - Cannot find resource named 'resource_name' defined in App.xaml
I'm relearning C# while also learning WPF with the MVVM pattern. I've ran into a little problem. When I try to run my app, I get an exception thrown at InitializeComponent(); from HardwareTestView.xaml.cs
I know there is a similar question/answer here, but it didn't seem to help me.
Error
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: ''Provide value on 'System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension' threw an exception.' Line number '39' and line position '14'.'
Inner Exception
Exception: Cannot find resource named 'BTN'. Resource names are case sensitive.

HardwareTestView.xaml.cs
public partial class HardwareTestView : UserControl
{
    public HardwareTestView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

}

It seems that it can't find {StaticResource BTN}. I doubled checked App.xaml, but everything matches.
HardwareTestView.xaml
<StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0 5 0 0">
    <Button Style="{StaticResource BTN}">
        <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/data/images/ExportTestRunResults.png"></Image>
    </Button>
    <Button Style="{StaticResource BTN}" Margin="5 0 0 0">
        <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/data/images/Eraser.png"></Image>
    </Button>
</StackPanel>

App.xaml.cs
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        MainWindow = new MainWindow
        {
            DataContext = new MainViewModel()
        };
        MainWindow.Show();
        base.OnStartup(e);
    }
}

App.xaml
<Application x:Class="TestInterface.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <!-- default style-->
    <Application.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="BTN" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="20 5 20 5"/>
        </Style>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>

Changing {StaticResource BTN} to {DynamicResource BTN} worked, but the button lost the default style.

I will admit not being an export on pack URI.  But looking at how we use it, after the ,,, part I think you want the full name of the Assembly in which the resource lives, followed by a semicolon and then the path.   Something like pack://application:,,,/MyApplication;data/images/Eraser.png.  Try that, replacing MyApplication with the proper full name

Or rather pack://application:,,,/MyApplication;component/data/images/Eraser.png.  Something like that

@Joe The Pack URIs are correct. You only need to include the referenced assembly name part when you load a resource from a different assembly. See here for reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#resource-file-pack-uris
